# ERROR 1064 (42000) error when inputting text data

Tags: mysql, bash

I have a script that creates a variable containing command line output. I want to add this variable to a field in mysql. It seems that mysql is not accepting the input because the `output` var contains certain characters. I look at the documentation but I'm not able to figure out how to have mysql just accept whatever text I trow at it. The mysql field type is set to TEXT.

Bash script to add the var

```
"INSERT INTO test (\`id\`, \`name\`, \`output\`, \`date\`) VALUES (null, '$name', '$output', '$date')"
```

Error

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat '/etc/openvpn/easyrsa3/pki/private/' at line 18
```

Comment: It looks like its failing to find the file `/etc/openvpn/easyrsa3/pki/private/`. Is it in your computer?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up working around the problem by using sed on the output.

```
output_new=$(echo "$output" | sed s/"'"/"\\\'"/g)
```

Answer (score 0):

change command like this

```
"INSERT INTO test (\`id\`, \`name\`, \`output\`, \`date\`) VALUES (null, \"$name\", \"$output\", \"$date\")"
```

Comment: It's best to explain why this error happened and why need to change the command as per your suggestion.